# Get time since current process was started in Node.js

Tags: node.js

Using Node.js, how can I compute the time since the current process (the one running node) was started?

Ideally I'd like a cross-platform solution but a macOS-only solution would also be okay.

Unfortunately it is impossible for me to inject any code into Node.js startup. My library will only be loaded at some unknown point after the process starts.

Answer (score 16):

The function `process.uptime()` (available since v0.5.0) returns the number of seconds the current Node.js process has been running.  I don't have a Mac to check, but there's no caveat in the documentation that it only works on certain platforms.

Comment: Note that the return value is a floating point number, not an integer.