# setTimeout _idleStart difference from Date.now()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, object

In JavaScript (node), the setTimeout(callback, time) function returns as object such as

```
Timeout {
  _called: false,
  _idleTimeout: 10000,
  _idlePrev: [TimersList],
  _idleNext: [TimersList],
  _idleStart: 1540487,
  _onTimeout: [Function],
  _timerArgs: undefined,
  _repeat: null,
  _destroyed: false,
  domain: [Domain],
  [Symbol(unrefed)]: false,
  [Symbol(asyncId)]: 1679,
  [Symbol(triggerId)]: 5 }
```

In order for a correct calculation of the time that has passed since the timeout started, I will have to record the timestamp as I am starting the timeout. BUT, there is this _idleStart variable which presumably recorded the start time.

Printing both Date.now() and timeout._idleStart shows a clear difference (both were run at the same time).

```
> Date.now()
1557468948157
```

Can you explain the difference between the two variables, especially what _idleStart is?

Comment: Where did you get `timeout` from? I get "ReferenceError: timeout is not defined".... I guess `_idleStart` is not an unix based timestamp, but the time passed since you started the process or opened the page.

Comment: sorry it is setTimeout. the function used to wait for a specific amount of time and callback. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Comment: For people that might get confused, in browser you get ID but in node, you get this object

Comment: updated the question. Thanks @rajesh

Comment: Given that this object is not standard, it may very well change in future versions of node. Not sure you should rely on it, but anyway, `setTimeout(()=>{})._idleStart === process.uptime() * 1000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_idleStart` is the number of milliseconds since the Node session was started, and is a static value created when `setTimeout` is called.

`Date.now` is the Unix epoch (milliseconds since 1st January 1970).

So, if you wanted to calculate when you started your Node session using `setTimeout`, you could do this:

```
var time = Date.now() - setTimeout(() => {}, 0)._idleStart;
```

Comment: Nah, use the [correct tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40901016/get-time-since-current-process-was-started-in-node-js)

Answer (score 0):

`Date.now()` will return the number of milliseconds that have elapsed since Jan 1, 1970 00:00:00 UTC. However, `_idleStart` is the number of milliseconds since the Node.js session was started.

Comment: Thanks, do you know where I can access the node session object (to get the time start).  Just curious.

Comment: To get the amount of time that the node session has been up for, use `global.process.uptime()`